# Android - background thread garbage collection

Tags: android

```
 public class MainActivity extends appCompatActivity{

        private void taskDone()
        {
            System.out.print("done");
        }

        public void startBackgroundThread()
        {
            new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                 MyLongrunnigTas.perform();
                 taskDone();
                }

            }.start();

        }


        //...
```

When startBackgroundThread() is called, Will it be garbage collected,after the thread executes, even though the activity is destroyed ( eg. by a orientantion change ).

Or will this cause a memory leak ??

Comment: It will cause a memory leak

Comment: Don't use Thread directly for background task. Use Async Task to perform background task as they are designed to work with android.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Yah, im trying to understand the negative effects. My primary qn is will it be garbage collected after tread execution, even if we are not in that activity anymore

Comment: @UmarHussain Totally wrong.  AsyncTask has a LOT of caveats.  Sometimes its the right answer, but frequently Thread is better.

Comment: @UmarHussain For example-  AsyncTasks all run on the same thread in round robin order.  That means a long running task will choke off all other async tasks.  An AsyncTask should only be used if the task is short, requires work to be done on the UI thread when finished, and does not necessarily need to run immediately.  It actually should almost always NOT be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread will be garbage collected according to the normal rules-  when no GC roots reference it anymore.  Since a running thread is automatically a GC root itself, it won't be possible to collect until after the thread finishes running.  Whether its elligble then or not depends on if any other variable holds a reference to it.  In your example, where it isn't saved anywhere, it will not be eligible until the thread finishes.

As for the Activity-  since the Thread is an annonymous inner class, it will have a reference to the class its defined in-  your MainActivity.  So until the thread is finished running the MainActivity, and all its variables, will not be garbage collected.  This includes the entire View hierarchy, so this is a bad leak.

Comment: clarification : in this case, after thread executes, it will be garbage collected, without a leak . right ?

Comment: Assuming no other leaks, yes.  If the thread is short lived (a few seconds) its not bad.  If its something that can last a prolonged time it can be an issue.